# Displaying array (of indeterminate length) returned by VBA in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have an Excel VBA function that compares two ranges and returns the values of cells in range A not found in range B.   I would now like to display the list of missing values in a different Excel worksheet.  Ranges A and B are hundreds of cells long. The missing values from A in B will usually could be from 0 to a dozen or two.  I'm not interested in just highlighting cells with conditional formatting.

The function is called multiple times in one sheet, creating a table.  The output looks like this:
[image: Example Table]

My current solution is to create an output range for each column with an array (Control Shift Enter) formula, that calls my function. `{=MyFormula(range1, range2)}`.  With the parameter being different for each column's array formula.

Within the function I then set the output array to be the same dimension as the array formula range:

```
    With Application.Caller
        CallerRows = .Rows.Count
        CallerCols = .Columns.Count
    End With
    ReDim Result(1 To CallerRows)
```

As I fill out `Result` if only fill it to N-1 spaces with the result, and in the Nth space I put something like '4 more entries...'

Obviously this is somewhat awkward, in that data is lost.  I could, of course, just expand the CSE range even more, but as such things go, if I make it 25 rows, tomorrow I'm sure to get an instance where 26 differences are found.

To my question:

- Is there a way to dynamically change the range of an array formula?
- OR should I somehow just do a raw paste of the values into normal cells (assuming there is no more data underneath the output range so I can add as many entries as possible)?

I'm guessing the first is likely impossible, but I want to confirm.

So if I go with the second option, what is the best way of doing it while keeping a function call in a cell, rather than a "repopulate" button or the like.

For reasons beyond my control, I'm currently limited to Excel 2013 for this application.

Comment: https://www.excelcampus.com/functions/dynamic-array-formulas-spill-ranges/

Comment: @TimWilliams - I should have stated (and have now edited) that I'm in lovely Excel 2013 land.

Comment: Not within a UDF.  Instead of entering your array formula over a range, use `INDEX` to display each element.  Then you can use the normally entered formula such as `=IFERROR(INDEX(your_formula,ROWS($1:1),1),"")` and fill down **many** more rows than needed.

Comment: @rosenfeld - it’s the filling down “many” rows that I was trying to avoid. I can fill down many rows on an array formula as well. Today “many” is 20 and tomorrow you find out it needed to be 30

Comment: It will show blanks if there are no matches. Your other option is a macro, and not a function.

Comment: Consider filling down a hundred cells then. Lock them so your users can't alter that range. It's much easier to add rows to an index formula then to modify an array formula.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with your function, but I'm going to assume you've added a new sheet and have it blank and ready to accept values. You've said that your function returns an array so you could do the following. I'm going to assume two things:

1. Your return array is called `myArray`
2. Your new sheet is called `mySheet`

```vb
Dim myR as Range
Dim item as Variant
Set myR = mySheet.Cells(1, UBound(myArray))

For i = 0 to UBound(myArray)
    myR(i + 1).Value = myArray(i)
Next i
```

It really is that easy.

Comment: Thanks.  The function gets called multiple times in one sheet and I need the results next to each other, in this case creating a table.  I'll update my question

Comment: My answer should still hold true. As long as you're pulling in an array, you can iterate through it. If you're running it multiple times, you can put each array into a collection with `Collection.Add` and then do a nested `For Each thing in myCollection... For i = 0 to UBound(myArray)...`

Comment: It looks like your method won't work, at least not how I envision it.  A UDF cannot change another cell in the worksheet.  Looks like I would need to code a sub that runs on all columns.  But then I'd need to figure out when to run it based on data changes (where as functions know when their parameters have changed)

Comment: @CarlosN check out `Workbook_SheetChange` in [the documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetchange)